# Display contents of $_POST one bye one

Tags: php, post

Hello I am submitting a form with POST method and I want its contents to be echo'ed one by one apart from the last one. So far I am using

```
<?php foreach($_POST as $data){
        echo $data;
} 
?>
```

which displays the whole array of $_POST, how can I make it using common "for" loop to not echo the last item of the array? It doesnt seem to work

```
    <?php 
    $length=count($_POST)-1;
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
        echo $_POST[$i];
        ?>
        <br>
    <?php } ?>
```

I am getting 5 errors, undefined offset 0 through 4 where the echo line is present

Comment: then just use `for` loop, get the count first. then add an if statement checking the current iteration against the count, then skip it. is this a school assignment? you should study loops, its one of the fundamentals

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the problem clearer, I am familiar with the for loop however I am missing something here

Comment: What do you mean "last"? $_POST is an associative array.

Comment: in my case I am submitting a form with 5 items, I want all of them to be printed but the fifth one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $lastItemOrder = count($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $value) {
        $counter++;
        if( $counter !== $lastItemOrder) {
            echo $value;
        }?>
        <br><?php 
    } ?>
```

Your loop for just get numerical index like $_POSR[0], $_POST[1]... This just would work if in the HTML the attribute name of the input elements be numerical also, like name="0" and so on.

foreach perform loop on array independently of index, numerical or string.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $lastItemOrder = count($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $index => $value) {
        $counter++;
        if( $counter !== $lastItemOrder) {
            echo $index . ": " . $value;
        }?>
        <br><?php 
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok now I get it, I didnt know the difference between associative and numeric arrays. I fixed it with an if statement